# How can I forbidden user to enter the home?

Tags: laravel

I have in users table column named ( active ) the value is 0 by default if ( 0 ) forbidden him to enter to home and if ( 1 ) it's ok to enter , of course the admin in admin panel control with that

so I wanna to say after the register or login forbidden him still active the account by admin ..

I'd create middleware for that but not working !!

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {
    if(auth()->user()->active == 1){
        return $next($request);
        return redirect('home');
    }else{
        return redirect('login');
    }
 }
```

and route code :

```
Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => 'is_active'], function() {

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And have you registered your middleware in `App\Http\Kernel.php` class?

In the `$routeMiddleware` array add this:

```
'is_active'       => 'App\Http\Middleware\YourMiddleware'
```

Then the usage can be simplified to this:

```
// check if the user is authenticated first because auth()->user() might return null which will throw an exception.
// also 1 is true anyway so no need to compare it. 0 is false.
if(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->active){
   return $next($request);
} else {

   // have to logout the user in order for the login page to show
   Auth::logout();

   return redirect('login')->with('message', 'Your account is being processed, please wait for approval');
}
```

In the `login.blade.php` add this somewhere:

```
@if(sessions()->has('message'))
<p>
    {{ session('message') }}
</p>
@endif
```

Comment: And with your code still the same problem ( This page isn’t working )

Comment: I added the logout now, because if you want to logout the user, you'll have to do that manually, try that. Make sure that it goes to the else statement. You can debug the process using `dd(auth()->user()->active)` take a look what it returns.

Comment: thank you so much it's work , but the question why you don't put the value of active in if like ( auth()->user()->active== 1 ) and can you explain this code ( if(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->active) )

Comment: I've answered your questions in a comment above the code, please check.

Comment: thank you so much :)  , I have another question now when any user do login form login page is not appear to him any think say like ( your account under processing ) or some like that > how can do something like that ? if you wanna to create new question it's okk with me and if you help me with that  here I'll be thankful .

Comment: Haven't tested it, but please check my edit, that should work. And yes if you have another question after this please create new issue, as this one is not connected with the title now :)